# React-router v6 private route not working well

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to implement private and public routes with react-router V6, I have tried all the available solutions on StackOverflow, it does not seem to work. That's why I needed clarifications.

```
// App.tsx 
<Suspense
          fallback={
            <Flex height={"90vh"} justifyContent="center" alignItems={"center"}>
              <Spinner colorScheme={"primary.400"} />
            </Flex>
          }
        >
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <Dashboard />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/product/:id"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <ProductDetails />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route
              path="/upload"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <Upload />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>


// PrivateRoute.tsx
    export const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: any) => {
      const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    
      if (user) {
        console.log("Yes, user exist");
      } else {
        console.log("No user");
      }
    
      if (!user) {
        return <Navigate to="/login" />;
      }
    
      return children;
    };
```

When I'm logged in, I can still navigate manually to the login page, and it renders, instead of pushing me to the dashboard page. Why??

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your issue. What is not working as expected? If you try to reach the login page when you are logged in, and it renders, it is the expected behavior. If you want to be redirected to the dashboard component, you have to implement this logic in the login component (smth like if (user) then navigate to Dashboard else render login component). So in the end, your issue doesn't seems to be related to private routing, but just with routing: you have to handle when a user is redirected to the dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `"/login"` path is just regular unprotected route, so I'd expect a user (*any user*) to be able to access that route unrestricted.

What you can do is to create a sort of "inverse" of your `PrivateRoute` that checks the authentication status and bounces users that ***are*** authenticated. Routes like this are commonly called "anonymous" routes.

Example:

```
export const AnonymousRoute = ({ children }: any) => {
  const user = localStorage.getItem("user");

  if (user) {
    console.log("Yes, user exist");
  } else {
    console.log("No user");
  }

  if (user) {
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return children;
};
```

Usage:

```
<Suspense
  fallback={
    <Flex height={"90vh"} justifyContent="center" alignItems={"center"}>
      <Spinner colorScheme={"primary.400"} />
    </Flex>
  }
>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route
      path="/dashboard"
      element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <Dashboard />
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />
    <Route
      path="/product/:id"
      element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <ProductDetails />
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />
    <Route
      path="/login"
      element={
        <AnonymousRoute>
          <Login />
        </AnonymousRoute>
      }
    />
    <Route
      path="/upload"
      element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <Upload />
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
</Suspense>
```